# C++11 Hash function for any enum type

Tags: c++, templates, enums, c++11, hash-function

I am writing a hash function for my object. I already can hash containers, and combine hashes, thanks to [Generic Hash function for all STL-containers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6899392/generic-hash-function-for-all-stl-containers). But my classes also have enums. Of course I can create a hash function for every enum, but it does not seem like a good idea. Is it possible to create some generic specification for `std::hash`, so that it could be applied to every enum? Something like that, using `std::enable_if` and `std::is_enum`

```
namespace std {
  template <class E>
  class hash<typename std::enable_if<std::is_enum<E>::value, E>::type> {
  public:
    size_t operator()( const E& e ) const {
      return std::hash<std::underlying_type<E>::type>()( e );
    }
  };
};
```

PS. This code does not compile

```
error: template parameters not used in partial specialization:
error:         ‘E’
```

Answer (score 11):

Your `E` parameter cannot be deduced, because the compiler cannot know that your `enable_if<...>::type` ends up denoting `E` again (and in fact, there are some specializations of it that by design don't do that!). It's called a "non-deduced context" for `E`.

If `hash` has only one parameter, there is no way (that I am aware of) to SFINAE out your partial specialization.

Answer (score 4):

If you're willing to use macros, you could dump the correct std::hash specialization next to your enum declaration.

Otherwise, the only way I've found to easily hash enum values is to generalize the hash type:

```
struct enum_hash
{
    template <typename T>
    inline
    typename std::enable_if<std::is_enum<T>::value, std::size_t>::type
    operator ()(T const value) const
    {
        return static_cast<std::size_t>(value);
    }
};
```

and using it that way:

```
enum class E { a, b, c };
std::unordered_map<E, std:string, enum_hash> map;
map[E::a] = "a";
```

Answer (score 2):

What you're trying to do is prohibited by the standard.

> [namespace.std]
>
> The behavior of a C++ program is undeﬁned if it adds declarations or
>   deﬁnitions to namespace std or to a namespace within namespace std
>   unless otherwise specified.
>
> A program may add a template specialization for any
>   standard library template to namespace std only if the declaration
>   depends on a user-deﬁned type and the specialization meets the
>   standard library requirements for the original template and is not
>   explicitly prohibited.

So you can certainly pursue some of the ideas in these answers, but you can't call it std::hash.  Defining your own 'enum_hash' template seems like a good idea.